# Cloning text (would add image but can't)

Tags: html

Basically these two are supposed to have different text inside the respective "div" elements- however sometimes I get an error which causes questions to be duplicated... - https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2AES.png where it should be https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I9Pi.png

I can't replicate the error, and I'd like to know what's going on!

The list should go 1,2,3 and so on... but when this error occurs I get 1,1,2,2,3,3 and it essentially doubles the questions- however you can't press the next button on this questionnaire to be able to complete the test.

This is a freak occurence, I and many others are unable to replicate the issue, but it keeps popping up.

<`div class="TEIQQuestionHeaderAgree">

<`div class="TEIQQuestionHeader">

<`div id="mainContent_TEIQQuestionControl_rptQuestions_pnlQuestion_0" class="TEIQQuestion">

```
<`span id="mainContent_TEIQQuestionControl_rptQuestions_rblAnswer_0" class="radioList"></span>

<`span class="questionNumber">

1:

</span>
<`span class="questionText">

Expressing my emotions with words is not a problem…

</span>
&lt;input id="mainContent_TEIQQuestionControl_rptQuestions_hdnQuestionID_0" type="hidden" value="3234" name="ctl00$mainContent$TEIQQuestionControl$rptQuestions$ctl00$hdnQuestionID">&lt;/input>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

<`div id="mainContent_TEIQQuestionControl_rptQuestions_pnlQuestion_1" class="TEIQQuestion">

```
<`span id="mainContent_TEIQQuestionControl_rptQuestions_rblAnswer_1" class="radioList"></span>

<`span class="questionNumber">

1:

</span>
<`span class="questionText">

Expressing my emotions with words is not a problem…

</span>
&lt;input id="mainContent_TEIQQuestionControl_rptQuestions_hdnQuestionID_1" type="hidden" value="3234" name="ctl00$mainContent$TEIQQuestionControl$rptQuestions$ctl01$hdnQuestionID">&lt;/input>
<`div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Freya, please include the HTML and CSS you used to get the output. Your current code is not so good for us to check out.

Comment: A link to the live site where this is occurring and/or a fiddle that replicates the issue would be helpful as well.